# SUM of elements of N Arrays using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, arrays, sum, java-stream

I can have N arrays of different lengths.
**Important thing** is that I don't know how many arrays I can have.
Let's have a example with just 3 arrays:

```
Integer arr1[] = {5, 10, -5};
Integer arr2[] = {8, 3};
Integer arr3[] = {12, -1, 0, 9};

List<String> result = Arrays.stream(arr1)
        .flatMap(s1 -> Arrays.stream(arr2)
                .flatMap(s2 -> Arrays.stream(arr3)
                        .map(s3 -> s1 + s2 + s3)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is it possible to do such a thing for N Arrays, using Stream?

Here guys. Another example with the expected result

```
 Integer arr1[] = {2, 4, 5};
 Integer arr2[] = {2, 4, 5};
 Integer arr3[] = {2 , 4, 5};

 List<Integer> result = Arrays.stream(arr1)
                .flatMap(s1 -> Arrays.stream(arr2)
                .flatMap(s2 -> Arrays.stream(arr3)
                .map(s3 -> s1 + s2 + s3))).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

                 System.out.println(" List of results: "+result);


              // List of results: [6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15]
```

Comment: Are those suppose to be int arrays?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that

Comment: No worries man, hope the answer helps.

Comment: Why is it that you expect a `List<String> result`? and could you share the expected output of the given input as well?

Comment: For the overall sum of all the elements, you can make use of `int sum = Stream.of(arr1, arr2, arr3)
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .mapToInt(i -> i)
                .sum();`

Comment: @CristianoBertolini - What are you really trying to do ? Please describe it in words. One cannot understand what you want by reading your code because your code could be incorrect.

Comment: @Naman - consider putting it as answer. much simpler than what i did.

Comment: I put another example with the expected answer.  Is more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want sum of all ints in arrays you can do like this:

```java
int sumOfAll = Stream.of(arr1, arr2, arr3)
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .mapToInt(v -> v)
    .sum();
```

If you want a list with sum of ints on given position, then you can do like this. Compute max length in arrays and then use it to insert default value if current list is to small.

```java
int max = Stream.of(arr1, arr2, arr3).mapToInt(a -> a.length).max().getAsInt();

List<Integer> reduce = Stream.of(arr1, arr2, arr3)
    .map(a -> Stream.of(a).collect(toList()))
    .reduce((a, b) -> IntStream.range(0, max)
        .mapToObj(i -> (i < a.size() ? a.get(i) : 0) + (i < b.size() ? b.get(i) : 0))
        .collect(toList()))
    .get();
```

#### UPDATE

If you want to achieve what you showed in the second example then it could be done like below.

- Create `List<List<Integer>>` that collects all ints that are needed to summing.
- Do the summing operation for every list.

```java
List<List<Integer>> integersList = Stream.of(arr11, arr12, arr13)
        .map(a -> Stream.of(a).map(x -> Arrays.asList(x)).collect(toList()))
        .reduce((a, b) -> b.stream().flatMap(v -> a.stream()
                        .map(x -> {
                                    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(x);
                                    ints.add(v.get(0));
                                    return ints;
                                }
                        )
                ).collect(toList())
        ).get();
```

It gives:

> [[2, 2, 2], [4, 2, 2], [5, 2, 2], [2, 4, 2], [4, 4, 2], [5, 4, 2], [2, 5, 2], [4, 5, 2], [5, 5, 2], [2, 2, 4], [4, 2, 4], [5, 2, 4], [2, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4], [5, 4, 4], [2, 5, 4], [4, 5, 4], [5, 5, 4], [2, 2, 5], [4, 2, 5], [5, 2, 5], [2, 4, 5], [4, 4, 5], [5, 4, 5], [2, 5, 5], [4, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5]]

Then summing it:

```java
List<Integer> sum = integersList.stream()
        .map(a -> a.stream().reduce(Integer::sum).get())
        .sorted().collect(toList());
```

Final result:

> [6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15]

Comment: Added Upaded @Cristiano Bertolini

Comment: That is it! your final result is correct! But, it works for 3 arrays. I don't know how many arrays I will have. The number of arrays is always >= 2.  

These arrays are in a List like this

`List<Integer[]> myarrays = new ArrayList();`

then, to get each one

`Integer[] arr1 = myarrays .get(i);`  

So, the problem is how I could use your solution for N arrays.

Comment: In this example it was used `Stream.of(arr11, arr12, arr13)` but you can pas there as many arrays as you need. So if you have `myarrays` as you said then you can replace `Stream.of(arr11, arr12, arr13)` with `myarrays.stream()` @CristianoBertolini

Comment: 100% Correct. exactly!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. We create a Stream of all arrays, then map the sum of those arrays as Integers and find the max value.

```java
        int max = Stream.of(arr1, arr2, arr3)
                .map(array -> IntStream.of(array).sum())
                .max(Integer::compareTo)
                .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
```

Comment: this wouldn't compile for the presence of `IntStream.of(array)` called upon `int[]` and for what reason are you trying to find out a `max` in the answer which is nowhere close to the question asked?

Comment: This does compile but you're correct, I could have swore that at one point the user was asking for the `max` from all arrays. I could be wrong but it was possibly edited.

Comment: An edit that cannot be traced is possible only for few(~5 mins), and the answer was made 9 mins after the question. So not sure what you need to be swearing upon. And if you consider `arrN` to be an `Integer []`, this won't compile.

Comment: It doesn't need to be boxed, he could simply use int[]. Also, you provided a comment on the main post with the sum so i'm not sure why you're so confused as to why I provided sum.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your question what you want. So, we can only guess your problem and guess a solution. Please describe in words what you want to do. If your code is mostly incorrect, then you can expect people to give incorrect solutions. It looks like you want to find out the sum of N arrays. If yes, then here is the solution.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer arr1[] = {5, 10, -5};
        Integer arr2[] = {8, 3};
        Integer arr3[] = {12, -1, 0, 9};

        System.out.println(doSomething(arr1, arr2, arr3));
    }

    public static Integer doSomething(Integer [] ... arrays){
        Integer sumOfArrays = Stream.of(arrays)
                .map( array -> Arrays.stream(array)
                        .reduce(0, (sum, nextInt) -> sum + nextInt )
                ).reduce( 0, (allArraySum, arraySum) -> allArraySum + arraySum );
        return sumOfArrays;
    }
}
```